# How do I create a bar plot in R where each bar is the percentage of a categorical var for a group?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Say I have data in the following format:

```
categoricalVar,  numericVar,  responseVar
           Foo,           1,         TRUE
           Bar,           0,         TRUE
           Baz,           2,        FALSE
       ...
       ...
       ... MUCH MUCH MORE
```

I want to create a bar plot where the X axis would be the 3 different types of  `categoricalVar`, and Y axis would the percentage of them that turned out to be `TRUE`. A table would work too, like this.

```
           Foo,   Bar,   Baz
 respPct   0.4,   0.6,   0.9
```

So out of all the `Foo`s, the percentage of `TRUE` was 0.4.

The same thing for `numericVar` would be nice.

```
             0,     1,     2, ....
 respPct   0.1,   0.2,   0.2
```

Although I think it makes sense to group the numericVar together, as follows:

```
           0-5,  5-10, 10-15, ....
 respPct   0.2,   0.3,   0.6
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For this time I've [created example data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33031156/2204410) for you, but next time please give a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it a lot easier for other to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to transform your `numericVar` into a categorial variable. But let's first create some example data:

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(catVar = rep(c("foo","bar","saz"),each=10),
                 respVar = c(sample(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE), 10, replace =TRUE),
                             sample(c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE), 10, replace =TRUE),
                             sample(c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE), 10, replace =TRUE)),
                 numVar = sample(0:15, 30, replace =TRUE))
```

**1:** create a categorical variable for `numVar` with:

```
df$catNum <- cut(df$numVar, breaks = c(-Inf,5,10,Inf), labels = c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15"))
```

**2:** aggregate the data with:

```
df2 <- aggregate(respVar ~ catVar, df, FUN = function(x) sum(x)/length(x))
df3 <- data.frame(table(df$catNum)/30)
```

**3:** create some plots with:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=catVar, y=respVar)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df3, aes(x=Var1, y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Jaap. Sorry for not creating the data ahead of time. I'll be sure to do that next time

Answer (score 1):

```
   df <- data.frame(a = c("0-5", "5-10", "10-15"), respPct =  c(0.2,   0.3,   0.6))
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(aes( x= a, y = respPct), data = df) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]